# Magento 1 - Convert type Administrator to Guest in Reviews

Tags: review

I would like to change my own created reviews from type Administrator to Guest. Normally it should be an easy change inside the database but it isn't. I investigated the database with no luck. Type Customer has customer's id number value set up in a field, but for both types Administrator and Guest values are NULL. I would like to know where in database Magento makes the difference between types Administrator and Guest for a review.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In table [review_detail] there is a column named "store_id". If there is a value of 0 set for a row, that is a review created by Administrator.